# How to import a plug-in in Tilemill?

Tags: plugins, mapbox, tilemill

It's a pretty simple question but I can't find it anywhere.
Where do I put the HTML code from a plug-in in TileMill?

For example this one:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-heat-markers/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapbox.js plugins are meant to be used with [Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/), rather than TileMill. Mapbox.js is a library for integrating maps into your website, whereas [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) is a tool for designing those maps.